# Rewritting $\frac{\partial g^{ik}}{\partial x^k}$ in terms of $g$ instead of $g^{-1}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, geometry

I have the following
$$\frac{\partial g^{ik}}{\partial x^k}$$
which appears in a computation that I am doing. As you can see it is a derivative of the inverse of the metric tensor $g$. How can I rewrite it as a derivative of the metric tensor $g$, instead of its inverse?

All I know is that $g^{ik}g_{kj}=\delta^i_j$, but this does not seem to help because
$$ g_{ik}g^{ik}g_{kj} =g_{kj}=g_{ik}\delta^i_j $$
which is of no use.

What do I have to do to lower the indices?

EDIT:

$$\frac{\partial (g^{ik}g_{kj})}{\partial x^k} =\frac{\partial \delta^i_j}{\partial x^k}  =0 $$
$$g_{kj}\frac{\partial g^{ik}}{\partial x^k} =- g^{ik}\frac{\partial g_{kj}}{\partial x^k}$$

Comment: Try differentiating both sides of $g^{ik} g_{kj} = \delta^i_j$.

Comment: Also, your manipulations don't make sense as there are three $k$'s at once.

Comment: @knzhou I edited with your suggestion, does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0=\partial_k\delta^{i}_l=g^{im}\partial_k g_{ml}+g_{ml}\partial_k g^{im}$, $g_{ml}\partial_k g^{im}=-g^{im}\partial_k g_{ml}$ so $\partial_k g^{in}=\delta_m^n\partial_k g^{im}=-g^{im}g^{ln}\partial_k g_{ml}$. Finally, $\partial_k g^{ik}=-g^{im}g^{kl}\partial_k g_{ml}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So when you use the product rule in differentiation you need to introduce a new index to go through all the terms. Do you know of any literature that has these index manipulation tricks written down? I had no formal instruction in tensor stuff and every book I find only lists very basic rules.

Comment: @berrygreen The only rule you need is each implicit someone needs to introduce a new index. In this case, you need a new dummy index to rewrite the Kronecker delta as two metric tensors: your mistake was trying to recycle an index already contacted in your original expression.